# Click on an SVG element sometimes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a modal with a fixed position, which has `X` icon to close and I also implemented `clickOutside` logic, when you click outside of modal it closes it, and it is written like this

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const useClickOutside = (
  refs: Array<React.MutableRefObject<HTMLElement | null>>,
  handler: (event: any) => any
) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) => {
      for (let ref of refs) {
         if (event.target instanceof HTMLElement && (!ref.current || 
ref.current.contains(event.target))) {
           return;
        }
      }

      handler(event);
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
      document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener);
    };
  }, [refs, handler]);
};

export default useClickOutside;
```

and while this hook works it usually fails on this specific case, when I click SVG elements, this code gets triggered and modal closes, I am only passing ref of the parent element with position fixed to this hook as refs. notably, the problem is fixed when I add either `z-index: -1` to SVG element, or `pointer-events: none`, why does this happen, I have read that SVG has a different click context but I do not see what could be wrong from that perspective.